# .NET core app hosted on azure first request very slow

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I have an issue with my .NET core app hosted on Azure.
Everything works fine in production but the first request after an inactivity period is very very slow (sometimes up to 10-15 seconds).

I don't get where the issue comes from because it didn't happened previously when I was hosting the app on DigitalOcean.

I added below some screenshots of the app on Azure.
Could you please let me know if anyone of you already met a similar issue?

Thanks a lot!

**App Service Details**
[image: App Service Details]

**Linux Plan Details**
[image: Linux Plan Details]

**Slow Request Example**
[image: Slow Request Example]

**App Service Configuration**
[image: App Service Configuration]

Comment: Does your app use Azure-hosted databases? Could the database be the thing going to paused state and thus causing long initial load times after inactivity?

Comment: @SpaceBeeGaming yes I have 2 databases hosted on azure (one for ressources and one for identity). Both of them are in "Basic" pricing tier with 5 DTUs but I don't see any auto-pause...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? It seems to still be happening in Azure.

Answer (score -1):

If you deploy with deployment slots, you can leverage warming-up.
You can even customize the operation: see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#specify-custom-warm-up)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think it is linked to the deployment... My app is deployed since several weeks and honestly, everyday after some inactivity hours the first request is very slow.

Comment: In the same documentation it says: "Deploying an app to a slot first and swapping it into production makes sure that all instances of the slot are **warmed up** before being swapped into production. This eliminates downtime when you deploy your app. The traffic redirection is seamless, and no requests are dropped because of swap operations. You can automate this entire workflow by configuring auto swap when pre-swap validation isn't needed."

Isn't this what you were looking for?
Btw - this is not "deployment", this is "deployment slots".

Answer (score -1):

This is expected behaviour and happens on local IIS deployments as well.

When you deploy a new version of your site to azure and subsequently make a request to it, it will need to load the resources it depends on into scope which will then be available for the lifetime of that service.

In Production, it might be wise to call the healthcheck pages (which you should already have!) which will alleviate this delay in the case of the resources going out of scope.

Comment: This is not only after deployment... My app is deployed since multiple weeks but everyday after some hours of inactivity the first request is slow.

Comment: @smil0h As said, this is typical behaviour. In standard IIS, the application pool will recycle and it is not until the first request after that point will it have loaded all the resources. I can only assume this behaviour is the same with an Azure web application.